# Symfony Admin generator - show Doctrine Collection

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In my model i have:

```
 * @method Doctrine_Collection getComments() Returns the current record's "Comments" collection
```

Default if i generated admin then this isn't showing in list.
If is in generator.yml :

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:    
    display: [id, title, comments]
  filter:  ~
  form:    ~
  edit:    ~
  new:     ~
```

Then this show me

```
<pre> Doctrine_Collection data : Array( ) </pre>
```

instead of list of comments.

I know - i can get files from cache and showing this, but maybe this is possible only with **generator.yml** ?
For example if i have relation one to many then this showing me this name.

I dont want use cache  for this!
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a function for your problem.

For example, in my `generator.yml`

```
  list:    
    display: [id, description, public, nbQuestions]
```

nbQuestions is a function in `Object.class.php`

```
public function getNbQuestions() {
    return $this->getQuestion()->count();
}
```

The admin generator will automatically call the "getYouField" Method in the object class. So you can describe a function which return a long string for you doctrine collection.

Answer (score 1):

There is an other way than only displaying a count.

You can add a partial in your generator.yml:

```
  list:
    display: [id, description, public, _comments]
```

Then in your partial (`_comments.php`), you can call the relation and display what ever you want (add style, other infos, etc ..):

```
<?php
  // note that you will need to change the $object
  echo $object->getComments()->count();
?>
```

In an other way, it could be usefull to have all comments listed in the edit view. In your generator.yml:

```
  form:
    # don't forget to add others fields
    display: [_comments]
```

And then in your partial:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach($form->getObject()->getComments() as $comment): ?>
    <li><?php echo $comment->getBody() ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

And if you want to combine both in the same partial (don't forget to rename `$object`):

```
<?php if(isset($form)): ?>

  <ul>
    <?php foreach($form->getObject()->getComments() as $comment): ?>
      <li><?php echo $comment->getBody() ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>

<?php elseif(isset($object)): ?>

  <?php
    // note that you will need to change the $object
    echo $object->getComments()->count();
  ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```